# Which of the following statements about a Dictionary is false?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, key-value

This was a quiz question. I think i got the right answer but one of the options i thought was false as well. Can you please explain? Thanks!

**C#: Which of the following statements about a Dictionary is false?**

> A) A dictionary can hold objects
>   B) A dictionary key and value cannot be different types
>   C) Two keys can have the same value. (Is this statement ambiguous?)
>   D) A specific key can only appear once in a dictionary.

I think B is false. The Key can be int and the value an Object. I guess that was the answer I should have picked. That answer was the reason I was writing this post. But i answered C because i read it wrong even though i thought D was in contradiction of C.

So i guess the real answer is as i suspected: B.

Comment: B is false. And C isn't ambiguos. You can have two keys with same value. Key is the one have to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) A dictionary can hold objects

This is true.  Dictionary in c# are generics (unless you code yourself a specific dictionary that is not generic)

B) A dictionary key and value cannot be different types.

This is false. It is common to see a dictionary of string(key) with Object(value).

C) Two keys can have the same value. (Is this statement ambiguous?)

This is true.  If we mean the value of the key itself, the statement is false.
If we mean the value in the dictionary represented by a key, then it is true. The same object could of been assign to both keys.

D) A specific key can only appear once in a dictionary.

This is true. it is the essence of the dictionary.

Comment: "This is true. If we mean the value of the key itself, the statement is false." Well, it wouldn't be false. Either the two keys are the same (since they're the same value), or they're different keys which hash to the same value, resulting in a collision, which is fine :)

Comment: I"m assuming Rob that you mean one can be hashed and the other not hashed? I'm not sure I follow you. I'm a novice sorry. I still think it could have been worded better. "Two different keys can have the same value."  When you are taking a timed test quickly, it is not easy to see that something can be read two different ways. You just read it and you may not notice the alternative reading. One guy above says it is not ambiguous.